# What songs from the Rock Band discs don't import into later versions?

Tags: rock-band, rock-band-3, rock-band-2

I know there are certain songs that cannot be imported from one version of Rock Band into another due to licensing issues.  What songs from Rock Band and Rock Band 2 are restricted in this way?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

These songs can't be exported and played in other versions of Rock Band:

### Rock Band 1

- "Enter Sandman" by Metallica
- "Paranoid" by Black Sabbath
- "Run to the Hills" by Iron Maiden
- "Dani California" by Red Hot Chili Peppers ***
- "Black Hole Sun" by Soundgarden ***

  ***: This song *can* be exported and played in Rock Band 2, but couldn't be played in Rock Band 3 when it was released. However, it [can be played after installing a patch released November 8, 2011](http://www.rockband.com/forums/showthread.php?t=225612).

#### European version

The above, plus:

- "Monsoon" by Tokio Hotel
- "Hier Kommt Alex" by Die Toten Hosen *†*
- "Rock 'n' Roll Star" by Oasis *†*

  *†*: This song *can* be exported and played in Rock Band 2, but can't be played in Rock Band 3.

### Rock Band 2

- "Any Way You Want It" by Journey
- "Battery" by Metallica
- "Give It Away" by Red Hot Chili Peppers
- "Let There Be Rock" by AC/DC
- "Spoonman" by Soundgarden

#### Free downloads

These songs can't be *exported* from Rock Band 2, but [were made available as a free download for everyone](http://www.rockband.com/forums/showthread.php?t=212327). ([Xbox Marketplace link](http://marketplace.xbox.com/en-US/Product/Rock-Band-Free-Pack-01/7dee9ca7-f2f1-49db-833a-548410765c00))

- "A Jagged Gorgeous Winter" by The Main Drag
- "Conventional Lover" by Speck
- "Get Clean" by Anarchy Club
- "Night Lies" by Bang Camaro
- "Rob the Prez-O-Dent" by That Handsome Devil
- "Shoulder to the Plow" by Breaking Wheel
- "Supreme Girl" by The Sterns
- "Visions" by Abnormality
- "Welcome to the Neighborhood" by Libyans

### Lego Rock Band

Everything can be exported!

### Green Day: Rock Band

Everything can be exported!

### [Rock Band track packs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Rock_Band_track_packs)

Everything can be exported! (That's kind of the point.)

### The Beatles: Rock Band

**Nothing** can be exported! Music by The Beatles is only playable in The Beatles: Rock Band, and vice versa.

Comment: When you say "(To RB2 Only)" does that mean you can only import them to Rock Band 2, or that you are only blocked from importing them to Rock Band 2?

Comment: It means the exported song is playable in RB2, but not in RB3.